# Why whenever touching Server Explorer, database contents is erased?

Tags: sql-server-ce-4

**Update**

I've just found what's causing it but couldn't solve it :

When running the project, VS copies the SDF file to bin\Debug, therefore, any changes made to it, even if only refreshing the DB will cause it to be overwritten...

---

I've created a quick and dirty project to test SQL CE 4.0, designed a small table and added an *Update* button to save entered data. So far everything works, I close and reopen the application, data is loaded and shown in the DataGridView.

[image]

There is one issue however, whenever I make *any* changes in Server Explorer such as just refreshing the connection,

[image]

when I launch the application again, all the data I entered is gone.

[image]

Did I miss something ?

How I created the database :

- From Data Sources I've added a new data source, created a new connection, created a new database, answered yes for copying it to my project and modifying the connection.
- Then from Server Explorer I created a new table, added columns
- Finally, I reconfigured my data source so it recreates the data set, data table and the adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fix for it :

Do not copy it locally to the project folder, there won't be two versions with one overwriting the other.

Comment: Or set the Copy property to Never

Comment: But the changes are never seen when running the project.